# In monopoly, if a player owns all of a set of properties but one of the properties is mortgaged, is the rent still doubled for the other properties?

Tags: monopoly

In monopoly, if a player owns all of a set of properties (e.g. all three green properties) then the (unimproved) rent of those properties is doubled. Imagine now that one of the properties is mortgaged and somebody lands on one of the unmortgaged properties in the set. Is the rent still doubled even though one of the properties is mortgaged? On the one hand, the player still owns all three properties. On the other hand, only 2 of the properties are "active" in the sense that they aren't mortgaged.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever played with this rule, although it makes the reason for the games name a lot more obvious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, rent is doubled even if some of the properties are mortgaged.

[Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf)

> It is an advantage to hold all the Title Deed cards in a color-group
> (e.g., Boardwalk and Park Place; or Connecticut, Vermont and Oriental
> Avenues) because the owner may then charge double rent for
> unimproved properties in that color-group. This rule applies to
> unmortgaged properties even if another property in that color-group
> is mortgaged.

Comment: I think that a certain amount of confusion arises from the fact that you can't build houses on unmortgaged properties when one or more is mortgaged. But you can collect "double" rent from unmortgaged properties in such a group.